# Magento - clicking on parent category returns a 403 error

Tags: magento

I have a problem with my Magento 1.5.0.1 installation.

Clicking on subcategories works fine and will send me to the proper URL and display products. When I click on a parent category however, I get a 403 forbidden error.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: i got same problem please help me out from this issue

Comment: I also check my log and also clearing my log  and refresh magento cache to get and idea.but not having any errors in log file too!

Comment: what is your category url ? Isn't it a protected/reserved word ?

Comment: no @dagfr we are not using any protected word!

Comment: Is this is a specific parent category, or all of them?  Do you have access to your apache `error_log` file?  The `error_log` will usually tell you what is causing the 403.  403 errors are permission based errors, meaning the server is denying access based off a security setting.

Comment: @Axel no i have no access of the apache error_log!

Comment: Could you paste in you .htaccess file contents? And show us the url(s) which is/are not working?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons that a category link would 403.

My first guess would be that there is a directory in the web root with the same name as the category and you have URL suffixes disabled.

For example giving a top level category the URL key of 'media' while URL suffixes are disables will usually result in a 403.

Another possibility would be if you are using Apache and have mod_security enabled and the category name contains a work that mod_security doesn't like (e.g. select, insert & delete).